# MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not working in android sdk 31?

Tags: android, kotlin

I upgraded my apps targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to SDK 31, and MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE not getting permission to access files.

Comment: That is strange. It should work. Here it works. What exactly is it that you dont get?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Android storage management policy has changed since SDK 30.
**MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** is replaced by **MANAGE_ALL_FILES**.

If you wish to work with **MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** change **targetSdkVersion** to **29** and add this to your **application** **manifest**:

**`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`**

Comment: I want to get files from Storage in Android 11 without going to setting to allocate permission?

Comment: So do change targetsdk to 29 and android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true". this will also work on android 11+.

Comment: But when upload on playstore they ask me target sdk and i want to use latest? then what's the solution

Comment: PlayStore forces to use targetSdk 30. If you want to upload to PlayStore you must present information to convince Google to allow your app to use the All Files permission.

Comment: `MANAGE_ALL_FILES` ? Never saw that permission. It does not exist. There is only `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: [Check this link](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files)

Comment: [Also check this link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: The closest policy I can find in your link is "the `ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` intent action", but no `MANAGE_ALL_FILES` permission. This answer is really misleading.